# Web Scraping como inserir o resultado dentro da <img src=

Tags: php, web-scraping

Estou fazendo um *web scraping* de um site, porem gostaria que as imagens retornadas já viessem para mim dentro da `<img src=` mas não estou tendo sucesso

```
// Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) 
       echo $element->src . '<br>';
```

Tentei isso aqui por exemplo mas não funcionou

```
<img src".$element->src .."> '<br>';
```

Answer (score 3):

A sintaxe correta, caso seja no html é :

```
<img src="<?php echo $element->src;?>"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `XPath` para isso e usar o `getAttribute`.

```
// Inicia o DOM:
$html = $retorno_do_seu_curl;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

// Inicia XPath:
$xpath = new DomXPath($dom);

// Encontra todos os `<img>`.
$imagens = $xpath->query('//img');

// Faz um loop para cada imagem obtida:
foreach($imagens as $_imagem){

    // Obtem o `src` da respetiva imagem:
    echo '<img src="' . $_imagem->getAttribute('src') . '">';

}
```

[Teste isto clicando aqui.](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3ab4219dadc38c4c64f064556ebe190be498fb32)

---

Se não quiser usar o `XPath` basta utilizar o `getElementsByTagName` depois `getAttribute`.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$imagens = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');

foreach($imagens as $_imagem){

    echo '<img src="' . $_imagem->getAttribute('src') . '">';

}
```

Comment: Than you. Funciounou!